# How many zeroes does the current target have?

Tags: difficulty

I'm trying to get my head around the difficulty setting of Bitcoin. 
How can I calculate how many zeros the target string needs to start with?

Answer (score 11):

**17** judging by the latest blocks published on blockchain.info:
https://blockchain.info/block/0000000000000000057fcc708cf0130d95e27c5819203e9f967ac56e4df598ee

Comment: Thanks especially for the link to make it easy to find out the answer in the future, as well.

Comment: The future is now ;-)  Changed to **18**, https://blockchain.info/pt/block/0000000000000000008be77e83deb352669b55fbe8f5ed208005fc1a9830c06c  (since Feb 2017 as [this block](https://blockchain.info/block/000000000000000000e907ebdb890c7f46c0649829b60e98ff5cb5e2b83fcc77), perhps before).

Comment: An early block of  Mar' 2009 (block deep 6100) have  [8 zeros](https://blockchain.info/pt/block/00000000707f5eba0caca3b6e725956e92c62f68c114a239f49ca9cf2b043801)  (see same at [other explorer](https://blockexplorer.com/block/00000000707f5eba0caca3b6e725956e92c62f68c114a239f49ca9cf2b043801)).

Comment: Still 18 zeros in June 2018

Comment: December 2018, 19 zeros

Answer (score 3):

Clarifying: difficulty is a more human-friendly representation of the target. Tha target itself is not specified in terms of the amount of zeroes. This seemed to be the case with hashcash.

The more precise definition of the target is a maximum accepted number for the produced block hash. In this sense a certain hash with a certain number of leading zeroes may be accepted and another hash with the same amount of leading zeroes may not be accepted.

Comment: Hi Jonathas, we see that the  amount is growing, so, who (authority or Bitcoin-rule) define the amount?

Comment: Hum... See [current difficulty](https://blockexplorer.com/api/status?q=getDifficulty) and [target concept](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Target), this is the reference for number of zeros (!).